# Transform Web.config in visualStudio 2015 webproject

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web.config-transform

I was trying to add multiple web.config files , one each for multiple environments .For example Web.Debug.config,web.Release.config etc..

I am using VisualStudio 2015 and I need to do this for the web project in my solution . I tried with some nuget packages like slowCheeta .But when I right click on my web.config I am not able to see "Transform" context menu. Any suggestions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS2015 ,just Copy your web.config file and paste there itself ,then it will automatically adds  web.debug.config and web.release.config

Comment: All I'm getting is a file called web - copy.config. Does it make a difference if you are using a web site rather than a web application project?